# expand Tiny url in java

Tags: java

I want to write a code in java that takes a url identify whether it is tiny url or not. if yes then it will identify the url is malicious or not. if not malicious print the url...

Please can any body help me....

Answer (score 5):

You can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/redirects.html) to detect whether the URL is redirected to another location. After that it's a simple case of:

```
if (!isMalicious(redirectTargetURL))
{
    System.out.println(redirectTargetURL);
}
```

The `isMalicious(...)` implementation is left as an excercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

If you trust google to implement `isMalicious(...)` then they have done so with their [Safe Browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/).

Answer (score 0):

So 2 main things you want:

1. Identify if it's a tinyurl
2. Identify if the URL is malicious

The answer to part 1 is easy. Just check if the URL belongs to the domain 'tinyurl.com'. Should be straightforward to either test raw URL string, or the host part returned by the getHost() method of a java.net.URL object.

Part 2 is more difficult to code up from scratch...

First you will need your code to figure out where the tinyurl redirects to.

The next bit really depends on how you want to define 'malicious'. Detecting deceptive URLs will require a bit of work (e.g. finding the difference between something like www.stackoverflow.com and www.stack0verf10w.com), or comparing the target URL with a malicous URL list (there's sites that publish them). There's also checking for multiple redirects, popups, and the list of criteria could go on and on.